# codeIgniter sql uft fetching issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8

Following code is used to return area_name ans it included chinese characters.

```
    public function get_area_name($area_id)
    {
        $this->db->select("*");

        $this->db->from("area");

    $this->db->where("area_id", $area_id);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $obj_area = $query->_fetch_object();

        return $obj_area->area;
    }
```

In another function following code will get return value and broken character is returned.

```
   $area = $this->get_area_name($area_id);
```

In database.php, config is setup as following.

```
 $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
 $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

I don't think it doesn't matter uft-8 is setup for html header since issue in php file.
But, html header is set up with utf-8 too.

Comment: Is the data being stored correctly in your database? Is your database using the correct characterset to store it?

Comment: check database and column's charset it is set to utf8 or not